# Let user choose file type while saving a file in Web application

Tags: java, servlets, download

I'm working on a web application at the moment using Tomcat and spring framework. A CSV file is stored on the server, the path to the file and the filename is stored in the database.

A search button on a webpage would list all records in database, if user click on one listed item, a saving dialog would be displayed and the file will be saved locally.

I want a dialog like this opened when user click on one item, how can I do it with httpServlet? I can think about a solution is set `content-disposition` type in response header to 'attachment'. It would force the browser to download the file instead of trying to display it in browser. But I want user to be able to select the type for file download. Please take a look at the image below

[image]

Comment: In your browser only keep one popup asking for file type he/she would like to download then stream that particular type to user.I dont think b

Comment: You seem to somehow expect that this will magically convert the provided file to the "desired" type. This is untrue. Just provide/specify exactly the type (and associated default extension) as represented by the actual content you're writing to the response.

Comment: why do you think it is magic? Maybe I haven't fully understood the technology. But what I want is really similar to a native application, a Microsoft Word for example, editing a new document, then click on File -> Save as -> choose file type -> slick on save. Is it not possible to do in  a web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `Content-Type` response header to something that the browser is unable to render should prompt the user to save the file upon receiving the response. A value of `application/octet-stream` (arbitrary binary data) should do the trick.

However, since you expect the actual file content to be in different format depending on user choice, here's what you would need to do:

- create a link/form on your html page that will allow user to select a type and make a request to URL with proper extension (like `download/file.xls` for XLS or `download/file.csv` for CSV).
- in your servlet that handles these URLs, check the extension requested (easy) and then convert the file to expected format within your servlet (not so easy) and send it in response.

Comment: it would force browser to download the file but with default file extension. if you look at the image, I want the application to be able to save the file in different types like that..

Comment: @trung-bún do you want the user to be able to simply select a different extension or do you actually want the content to be in a different format depending on the user's choice, like either xls or csv?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I really want to do: the user needs to be able to select different file extension LISTED in the dialog! It just doesn't make sense to save a CSV file with docx extension right?

Comment: @trung-bún in that case it's actually much more complex since you need to implement server-side conversion of the file - see the edit to my original answer.

Comment: Thank you! Nearly 1hr research on this and I realize that it can't be done. Anw thank you very much.